# What's the relation of FDR and Wilson to War on Terror/terrorism in House of Cards?

Tags: united-states, history, terrorism, north-america

In House of Cards, Frank Underwood brings up FDR and Wilson when saying that he wants to declare war on ICO (fictional terrorist group possibly related to ISIS). What's the relation please? I mean, every president presumably has to deal with terrorism in some way so why those presidents specifically?

Cross-posted:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/118474/whats-the-relation-of-fdr-and-wilson-to-war-on-terror-terrorism

https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38432/whats-the-relation-of-fdr-and-wilson-to-war-on-terror-terrorism-in-house-of-car

[What's the relation of FDR and Wilson to War on Terror/terrorism in House of Cards?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75145/whats-the-relation-of-fdr-and-wilson-to-war-on-terror-terrorism-in-house-of-car)

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @F1Krazy But I didn't really get an answer there from someone who's seen the series

Comment: That movie comunity is defenetly the most suitable place for this question.

Comment: @F1Krazy Do you disagree with convert?

Comment: I personaly don´t see any disagreement.

Comment: @wrod based on the answer here in or in history SE I guess you don't really need to have seen the show?

Comment: Best scene in the series, by far.

Comment: House of Cards is a dramatization. This section of Stackexchange relates to real world politics, so this question is off-topic.

Comment: @BCLC that is true.  However, I can only understand what the question is asking by reading that answer.  This makes it a poorly-worded question.  It also doesn't allow for other answers, which may expose other sides of what is happening.  Further, it doesn't make it a re-usable question.  Because to someone pondering a similar inquiry in the future, it may not be immediately obvious that this question would be similar to theirs.

Comment: @MishaP how is there no real world politics here? FDR is fictional?

Comment: @Gouvernathor hunt or be hunted. There won't be a revolution because you freed one man.

Comment: @wrod ' that is true. However, I can only understand what the question is asking by reading that answer. This makes it a poorly-worded question' --> but how did the answerer there answer the question without having seen HoC?

Comment: @BCLC "he wants to declare war on ICO (**fictional** terrorist group possibly related to ISIS)" The situation is fictional. As is House of Cards and Frank Underwoods. Any aspect of the film is subject to the whims of the author. The presence of one real-world politician, and realistic, but fictional, political situations, does not make this a question about politics, but rather - about a particular fictional scenario in a series.

Comment: That's not to say, that I think it's a bad question - it's a great question, definitely related to politics, but if you want to keep it in politics, then I would rephrase the question, without mention of fictional characters or scenarios. For instance - "Can a country formally declare war on a terrorist organization?" or "Does declaring war on an organization (terrorist or not), imply declaring war on the country it is based in?"

Comment: @BCLC I am no sure that's a good standard.  Someone who knows the answer understands the question better than most, so they don't need the benefit of the answer being phrased well.  A good question should be understood by those who don't know the answer so that they can learn something from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the transcript, [House of Cards, Season 5, Episode 1](https://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/house-of-cards-2013-7mpe/s5/e1), Frank Underwood, addressing the House of Representatives.

> One of the murderers who killed Mr. Jim Miller is still out there.
>
> At large.
>
> How much proof do you need?
>
> I demand that every member of this House take a stand.
>
> Like FDR before, and Wilson before him.
>
> I demand that this Congress declare a formal declaration of war against ICO, both here and abroad.

Congress, for Wilson (WWI) and FDR (WWII), passed formal declarations of war under the US Constitution, [Article 1, Section 8, Clause 11](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S8-C11-1/ALDE_00001072/):

> To declare War, grant Letters of Marque and Reprisal, and make Rules concerning Captures on Land and Water;

Frank Underwood is demanding the same — a formal declaration of war — as was provided Wilson and FDR.

In a case of art imitating life, a Joint Resolution was introduced in the US Senate, [S.J.Res.46 - Declaration of War against the Organization known as the Islamic State](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/46), more that two years before the referenced *House of Cards* episode aired.

Comment: Which is complete and utterly nonsensical, since you can only formally declare war against a country. So, such a declaration would implicitly upgrade the ICO from "terrorist group" to "state", and grant their member protection under the Geneva conventions and other treaties. Which further shows that this kind of questions belongs to the TV stackexchange and not here.

Comment: @SJuan76 - [S.J.Res.46 - Declaration of War against the Organization known as the Islamic State](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/46). Art imitates life.